# Adding a box shadow error - Cant tap on my button - SpriteKit

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am trying to make a button with a nice soft box shadow around it to make it look a little 3d.

I have a normal button I imported and a extension on `SKSpriteNode`

When I click on the button it goes to my next scene (GameScene). Although, when I apply this 'glow', it shows up although now the button cannot be pressed anymore.

```
let playBtn = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "play-btn")
        playBtn.name = "play-btn"
        playBtn.addGlow()
        playBtn.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY + 70)

        addChild(playBtn)

extension SKSpriteNode {

    func addGlow(radius: Float = 10 ) {
        let effectNode = SKEffectNode()
        effectNode.shouldRasterize = true
        addChild(effectNode)
        effectNode.addChild(SKSpriteNode(texture: texture))
        effectNode.filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", withInputParameters: ["inputRadius":radius])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The effect is probably sitting on top of the button preventing you from accessing it. Try setting the zPosition's (layering of the objects)

```
let playBtn = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "play-btn")
playBtn.name = "play-btn"
playBtn.addGlow()
playBtn.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY + 70)
playBtn.zPosition = 1
addChild(playBtn)

extension SKSpriteNode {

    func addGlow(radius: Float = 10 ) {
        let effectNode = SKEffectNode()
        effectNode.shouldRasterize = true
        effectNode.zPosition = -1
        addChild(effectNode)
        effectNode.addChild(SKSpriteNode(texture: texture))
        effectNode.filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", withInputParameters: ["inputRadius":radius])
     }
}
```